# Find location of .csr file

Tags: linux, csr

I need to find the location of an existing csr file on my linux server, but I'm not sure where  it's stored.

What's the best way to find this out?

Answer (score 2):

If you have `locate` installed (it is part of GNU Findutils, may be included in your installation) then you can simply do:

```
locate myfile.csr
```

Otherwise you may have to search the whole filesystem with `find`:

```
find / -name "myfile.csr"
```

If you have some idea of where it might be (eg under a certain home dir or something) then you can specify that directory in place of the `/`.